# How to install OSM .pbf support in GDAL on Debian?

Tags: gdal, openstreetmap, sqlite, debian, ubuntugis

I'm trying to use [Anita Graser's post](http://anitagraser.com/2014/05/31/a-guide-to-googlemaps-like-maps-with-osm-in-qgis/) on loading OSM data from .PBF files into a SQLite .db file using ogr2ogr but it stopped working.

I'm trying to run the following command:

```
ogr2ogr -f "SQLite" -dsco SPATIALITE=YES Denver_OSM_Test.db denver.pbf
```

...yields the following error:

*Unable to open datasource `denver.pbf' [list of drivers]*

I'm trying this on both **Ubuntu 14.04** and **Linux Mint 17.2**

***Note**: This has worked cleanly before on Ubuntu 14.04 as per the instructions linked below which installed GDAL 1.9 or older... why this has stopped working is beyond me...*

I have installed the prerequisites:

- libsqlite3
- libexpat

Then tried to re-install GDAL both from source, and from [Sara's instructions](http://www.sarasafavi.com/installing-gdalogr-on-ubuntu.html) which pull from the UbuntuGIS project.

**EDIT**:

Versions:

Using `ogrinfo --version` I get `GDAL 2.0.0, released 2015/06/14`

Using `apt-cache policy gdal-bin` I get:

```
gdal-bin:
  Installed: 1.11.2+dfsg-1~exp2~trusty
  Candidate: 1.11.2+dfsg-1~exp2~trusty
  Version table:
 *** 1.11.2+dfsg-1~exp2~trusty 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.10.1+dfsg-5ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Which debian version are you running? I guess Ubuntugis packages are only running on the platform they were built for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you don't have a recent version of gdal. [OpenStreetMap PBF support in GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/drv_osm.html) was introduced in version 1.10.

Check your version and where it came from with:

```
apt-cache policy gdal-bin
gdal-bin:
  Instalado: 1.9.0-3.1
  Candidato: 1.9.0-3.1
  Tabela de Versão:
 *** 1.9.0-3.1 0
        500 http://ftp.pt.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

On my Debian, the GDAL version is still 1.9. PBF support is not included.

Comment: Debian Jessie (current stable version) has gdal 1.10.1.

Comment: I should mentioned that this is for Debian wheezy. If @mapBaker does not have Gdal 1.10 on the default repositories, I supposed he/she still has Debian wheezy. I have only Debian wheezy on a cloud provider, and I can not upgrade to jessie.

Comment: @jgrocha  will update my question with version summaries